# Session, Cache OR Cookies which one to use to retain Search Criteria of User? (Posted With Case Study)

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a Web application which is based on ASP.NET 4.0, JQUERY, AJAX and Javascript. I have a particular search page in which a user can search via multiple factors i.e. either by Date, Name, Code, Category etc.

For e.g.

A) In a SearchProducts form, user can search a product via its unique Number OR Name OR Start Date/End Date OR Category OR etc etc.

B) User can search by either one or all of the parameters which a standard search form should be able to do.

C) If user searches via Start Date and End Date say 1st Dec 2012 to 31st Dec 2012 so for example my Search Results consist of 4 Products i.e. 4 products are purchased from 1st Dec to 31st Dec

D) Results are displayed in the grid and by clicking on the Product Number its redirecting to its View page (selected Product Specific full details) with ProductID via  Query string.

E) **I have a requirement which enables the user to retain search results which he/she has searched via Back To Search button in View page (selected Product Specific full details) page**.

Now, What I have planned is as follows:

1) **When a user submits on the Search then I want to store the refference of Search Paramters i.e Date, Name, Category etc which user has entered.**

2) I will set a value in query string to differentiate normal request and request Via Back to Search button.

3) code in Search Page:

```
       if (!(IsPostBack))
       {
          string tempRequestMode = string.Empty;

          if (Request.QueryString["requestMode"] != null)
          {
              tempRequestMode = Request.QueryString["requestMode"].ToString();

              if (tempRequestMode == "searchResults")
              {
                 //RestoreValues();
                 //Fetch results from the database again based on above results
              }
          }
       }
```

Now, My question is:

I wanted to use **ASP.NET Cache** for this purpose:

**Advantages**: its expiration and dependencies

**Disadvantages**: its has the application scope i.e. its not per user wise as Session is.

Second option is **session**:

**Advantages**: its per user wise.

**Disadvantages**: Session is more memory intensive.

I am confused that what Should I use. Is there any other option to use as **Search Criteria is different for different users so want user wise maintenance of data**.

Comment: Any help is much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write all search criteria to QueryString.

When a User clicks the Search Button, run this Javascript:

CLIENT-SIDE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "Invoices.aspx?type=__type__&status=__status__&order=__order__";

    var type= $("#<%= drpType.ClientID%>").val(); // Type 
    var status = $("#<%= drpStatus.ClientID %>").val(); // Status Parameter
    var order = $("#<%= drpOrder.ClientID %>").val(); //  order Parameter

    window.location = url.replace("__type__",type).replace("__status__",status).replace("__order__",order).replace(");
</script>
```

SERVER-SIDE

```
  protected void Page_Load(object cart, EventArgs curt)
            {

                _type = Request.QueryString["type"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_type))
                    _type = Enums.InvoiceUserTypes.RS.ToString(); //Default

                _status = Request.QueryString["status"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_status)) _status = "ALL"; //Default

                _order= Request.QueryString["order"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_order)) _order = "date"; //Default



                drpStatus.Value = _status;
                drpType.Value = _type;
                drpOrder.Value = _order;

RunReport();
            }
```

When user click Back button . Search parameters will be on the URL

Comment: Thanx for the kind help @halit. I have the search button which binds the grid on the same page with search criteria. So the URL in product Number is generated as via MSSQL in SP i.e. productDetails.aspx?Pid=4 so in the details page I don't get the criteria. I think appending the search criteria via querystring in SP is not efficient. When I click on back to search button via details page, the url is productDetails.aspx?Pid=4 so cannot get the search criteria via query string in Searchproducts.aspx page.

Comment: You can redirect to samepage with different Queries. Productid is not a search criteria. And you can use Request.UrlReferrer to redirect Search results.

Comment: Yes Product ID is not the search Criteria but I have one view Page i.e. productDetails.aspx which shows the details of the product accessed via search results. for e.g.: Column of Product Code in grid has the <a> tags attached and generated in stored procedure for e.g. <a href="productDetails.aspx?PID=10">P00010</a> and I AM DISPLAYING THE SEARCH RESULTS IN THE SAME PAGE IN ASPGRIDVIEW.

Comment: But It's Not Problem. You dont need to post page to bind Gridview.
You can bind it on page_Load.

Comment: According to URL Example, I don't want the values on invoices.aspx page but instead on same page. according to your example if I redirects to same page so my url will be SearchProducts.aspx?type=__type__&status=__status__&order=__order__ and bind the results via criteria. then I click on Product code link so will be redirected to productDetails.aspx page where my back to search button is. but in the current URL productDetails.aspx i don't get the querystring values as my url is generated via MSSQL stored procedure and url will be as productDetails.aspx?PID=10.

Comment: And If you don't want to change your scenario. You can keep search Criteria on the Session. When User visit Search Page and  Visitor has search criteria in the session. Use session criteria for Bind Gridview.

Comment: Ya But Session is memory intensive. I want some other option. Wanted to use cache but its not user wise. I am confused that what Should I use. Is there any other option to use as Search Criteria is different for different users so want user wise maintenance of data.

Comment: If you store only Search criteria without Results. Session is the best way. If You want to Keep all search result. I recommend that, Serialize Result Data and write to Hard Disk named with User SessionID. and remove it on the Session_End (Global.Asax) .

Comment: I want that particular session to be destroyed within 10 minutes instead of normal session timeout which is normal i.e. 20 minutes for an application. So have to write code for it. i.e. if storing time and current time has difference more than 10 minutes so it should be removed. is it ok ? Can I use Cookies ?

Comment: You don't need to use cookies. You can store CurrentTime like search criteria then you can compare time in session and DateTime.Now.

Comment: Ya I have to compare Date objects. By the way, I am thinking of your previous solution of appending querystring to on submit click on search page then passing those to SP then appending to the view page URL i.e. productDetails.aspx?PID=10&Name=kkkk&Date=10/12/2012 etc and then sending these querystings back to search page via back to search button. Is it fine @halit ?

Comment: You can use. Request.UrlRefferer  To get previous page url. You don't need to pass parameters to productDetails.aspx page. If Request.UrlRefferrer is null. Redirect to search page without params.

Comment: BUT my URL Refferer will be productDetails.aspx?PID=10 if I don't pass the params to the productDetails.aspx page.

Comment: My sequence Of Execution: 1) User has entered A in the Product Name field and Grid will show A in the results with the URL as <a href="productDetails.aspx?PID=10">P00010</a> so my page will be redirected with the PID querystring value if I do not append the querystring params.

Comment: you can Send query and path  like productdetails.aspx?id=5referrer=search.aspx%3Fparam1%3Dvalue1%26param2%3Dvalue2%26param3%3Dvalue3. You should encode refferer value while using HttpUtility.UrlEncode() or javascript encodeURIComponent. 
When user Click Search Button on the detail page. Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["refferer"]); But First check .refferer shouldn't be null.

Comment: Ok Thanks @halit bro. I think I will have to use Querystring as per your suggestion for the above requirement. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this case is to redo the search using the stored filters once the user gets back to the search page. Any other approaches will bring you a big drawback.

Caches Expire and if you use the default implementation they won't allow your app to scale to multiple machines since they are local.

Using sessions is a bad idea too because they will eat your resources AND won't allow you to scale too.

If you must store the results you should store them serialized ([LOB pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html)) in a database or another network accessible resource so you could retrieve them in any application server.

Comment: Thanks bro. I am storing ONLY criteria in session and WILL NOT store the search results in session @tucaz.